# React 'module not found' error (Flickity plugin)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, flickity

I'm trying to add a Flickity carousel to my application. After having followed the [instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flickity) on npm to the best of my ability I'm getting this error:

> ./~/flickity-fix/js/flickity.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'classie/classie' in '/Users/.../node_modules/flickity-fix/js'

I've added:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /flickity/,
        loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'
      }
    ]
}
```

To my config.js folder as I do not have a webpack config file (as I'm using create-react-app).

I've scouted around and some people are having similar issues (notably [here](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/225)) but I can't seem to make their solutions work for me.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have u imported it in the project files as well?

Comment: @MohhamadHasham I've 'required' it yes

Answer (score 1):

```
{ test: /node_modules\/flickity/, loader: 'imports?define=>undefined' }
```

in the webpack config, and `npm install imports-loader`

if you don't already have it.